# Django template tags within a hyperlink

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

In my .html file, I have this code:

```
<ul>
    {% for file in files %}
        <li><a href="{% static 'notebooks/<**Part that I want to reference dynamically**>' %}">{{ file }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In my views.py file:

```
def ipythonlist(request):
    files = [] 

    main_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static/'))
    ipython_file_path = os.path.join(main_dir, 'notebooks/')

    for file in os.listdir(ipython_file_path):
        if file.endswith(".html"):
            files.append(file)

    return render(request, 'pages/ipythonlist.html', {'files': files})
```

And my url file:

```
url(r'^ipython/list', views.ipythonlist, name='ipythonlist')
```

So what I am trying to do is get a list of all the .html files (or any type of files for that matter, pdf, csv, etc.) within a directory in my static folder. Then I pass this data from the views into my html using template tags. I want to link to that corresponding file dynamically, but I am not sure how to do that.

I tried {% static 'notebooks/{{file}}' %}, but that just returned an error.

Not sure how to do this and would appreciate some help!

So an example of the link to a file would be {% static 'notebooks/chapter9.pdf' %}. Where chapter9, can be any name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{% for file in files %}
    {% with file_with_path='notebooks/'|add:file %}
        <li><a href="{% static file_with_path %}">{{ file }}</a></li>
    {% endwith %}        
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables in your tags, though you can't interpolate them into strings like you're trying to do. You could add the path, with `notebooks/`, to `files` and use that in `{% static %}`:

```
# View
def ipythonlist(request):
    files = [] 

    main_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static/'))
    ipython_file_path = os.path.join(main_dir, 'notebooks/')

    for file in os.listdir(ipython_file_path):
        if file.endswith(".html"):
            files.append('notebooks/%s' % file)

    return render(request, 'pages/ipythonlist.html', {'files': files})

# Template
<ul>
    {% for file in files %}
        <li><a href="{% static file %}">{{ file }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```